# NGINX returns 404s when trying to cache static files

Tags: nginx, flask, web, caching, http-status-code-404

**Problem:**

When I attempt to add caching logic to my NGINX server.conf file all static assets receive a `404`

**Goal:**

I would like to serve specific files types within the /static/* file directory with caching headers via NGINX. I would like these headers to tell clients (browsers) to cache static files locally.

**Context:**

I will be using `www.example.com` instead of my own domain in this example.

I have two docker containers that are aware of each other. One is an NGINX server that receives web connections. The other is a Flask container that does backend processing and creates dynamic HTML templates with JINJA.

The NGINX container has a folder called /static which contains files such as .css, .js, .png, .jpg, and others. The /static folder structure looks like this:

**/static file structure**

```
     /static    
        ├── /assets
        │   └── sitemap.xml
        │   └── otherfiles...
        └── /img
        │   └── images...
        └── /js
        │   └── jsFiles...
        └── /css
        │   └── cssFiles...
```

**NGINX Config - *WORKING***

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name <www.example.com>;
        return 301 <https://www.example.com>$request_uri;
}

server {

    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name <www.mydomain.com>;
    ssl_certificate <certpath>
    ssl_certificate_key <privatekeypath>

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app-docker:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "User-agent: *\nAllow: /\nSitemap: https://<www.example.com>/sitemap.xml";
    }

    location /sitemap.xml {
        add_header Content-Type application/xml;
        try_files $uri /static/assets/sitemap.xml;
    }

    location /static {
        rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        root /static;
    }
}
```

**NGINX Config - *BROKEN***

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name <www.example.com>;
        return 301 <https://www.example.com>$request_uri;
}

server {

    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name <www.mydomain.com>;
    ssl_certificate <certpath>
    ssl_certificate_key <privatekeypath>

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    # ------ Start of caching section which breaks things ------
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    access_log off;
    }
    # ----------------------------------------------------------

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask-app-docker:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "User-agent: *\nAllow: /\nSitemap: https://<www.example.com>/sitemap.xml";
    }

    location /sitemap.xml {
        add_header Content-Type application/xml;
        try_files $uri /static/assets/sitemap.xml;
    }

    location /static {
        rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        root /static;
    }
}
```

**NGINX Config - *DIFF***

Here are the lines which are added to the file and break things:

```
    # ------ Start of caching section which breaks things ------
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    access_log off;
    }
    # ----------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT 11/9/2020**
Still unable to get caching working based on the ending file extension. However, I managed to get a work around going by placing static files into their own folder and then set cache headers on all files.

Updated the `/static` location block in my example above to look like this.
I may eventually update this to be the answer as it is working even though it is not the perfect solution or the answer I was looking for.

```
    location /static {
        root /static;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    }
```

Comment: exactly the same problem here - did you fix this? thx

Comment: Nope never got a fix. I managed to get a semi work around going. I just made an edit to my post

Comment: I got this working by moving the line ... root /usr/share/nginx/html; ... from my location block to my server block - apparently the root is the path to the static files and because root was in my location block (a different location block) there was no path to the files in the static file location block - by moving it to the server block then all location blocks seemingly inherit from this

Comment: thanks @danday74. I improvised on your suggestion. Instead of having it at the server level, add the root location to the new location block. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301181/1448511

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this same issue.
In general, the `location /` part will serve the HTML and its static files. Now we are adding another location part for specific file types to be cached. In that case, you need to set the root folder, which basically has your HTML and static files. In my case, `root /root/yourapp/dist;` is the folder path.

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg)$ {
     root /root/yourapp/dist;
     expires 30d;
     add_header Pragma "public";
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
location / {
      root /root/yourapp/dist;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      expires 30d;
    }
```